# Data binding: Can't pass list's size from xml to adapter

Tags: android, android-databinding

In my app/build.gradle:

```
dataBinding {
        enabled = true
}

kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.0.1"
```

xml layout with data binding:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="item"
            type="com.myproject.android.customer.api.model.Item" />
        </data>
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">        
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subTitleTextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="#a3a3a3"
                android:textSize="9sp"
                app:subtitle="@{item.offers}" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Adapter's code:

```
   @BindingAdapter("subtitle")
    public static void setSubtitle(TextView view, List<Offer> offers) {
        int offersCount = offers.size();
        String subtitle = ((offersCount == 1) ? String.format(view.getContext().getString(R.string.offer), offersCount)
                : String.format(view.getContext().getString(R.string.offers), offersCount));
        view.setText(subtitle);
}
```

OK. It's work fine.

But I want to pass only list's size to method `setSubtitle()`. I'm not need to pass whole list.

So here my changes:

in xml file:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/subTitleTextView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:subtitle="@{item.offers.size()}" />
```

and in adapter:

```
@BindingAdapter("subtitle")
    public static void setSubtitle(TextView view, int offersCount) {
        String subtitle = ((offersCount == 1) ? String.format(view.getContext().getString(R.string.offer), offersCount)
                : String.format(view.getContext().getString(R.string.offers), offersCount));
        view.setText(subtitle);
}
```

But I get error:

```
:app:kaptDebugKotlin
e: error: cannot generate view binders com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for io.reactivex.Flowable not found   
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:138)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:154)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:58)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
```

Comment: Do you have any other errors? There is nothing obvious from your code, but I *think* there should be other error messages that give a clue as to what specifically data binding doesn't like. If not, it looks like a bug -- if you submit it and post the bug link here, I can assign it to myself.

Comment: No other errors. Only this error

Comment: Only this error messages: `e: error: cannot generate view binders com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for io.reactivex.Flowable not found
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing`